# SQL Server 2012 - File table permissions for network access

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-permissions, filetable

I have a sql server 2012 instance set up as a filestore on a networked server. I need all users on computers on the same network to be able to browse the file system representing the file table. However all user can see the server, and top level directory but do no have permission to access/ open it.

What permissions should I be looking at to enable access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use myDatabase
go

grant view definition to [user]
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following code within SQL

```
ALTER DATABASE myDatabase
SET FILESTREAM ( NON_TRANSACTED_ACCESS = FULL )
GO
```

Providing that FILESTREAM is enabled for the instance, this has been done, and a valid directory has been specified, it should work.

Comment: The users can see the sql Instance and the top level directory but don't have access to the file table directory? I'm afraid this hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably consider providing a Domain Group (1) access to the server and (2) database containing the filetable and then grant (3) specific permission to each Filetable to allow them access to its contents.

This could be done by using either using individual GRANT statements (SELECT, DELETE, UPDATE, INSERT - optional ALTER if you want them to be able to browse at the server/instance/filetablefolder level) or creating a Database role and giving it these permissions and then linking the Domain Group to that role.

[some information on general FILETABLE access for users here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907827/how-to-enable-permissions-in-sql-server-2012-filetable-folder-share/31228394#31228394)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to SQL accounts "NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users"
and give access to database